# How can I close my ES connections while cancel the FLINK job?

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I want to get methods to do the resource management (such as init, close) in flink API.

eg.

When I submit a job to flink, some JDBC connections established.

When I cancel a job, these connections closed before job canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichFunction` interface provides `open()` and `close()` methods. `open()` is called when the task is started and before the first records are processed. `close()` is called when a task is canceled, due to a failure or on purpose.

For most functions there exists a rich variant, i.e, `RichMapFunction` for `MapFunction`.